# Find (and replace) adjacent equal/similar elements in List<int>

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, foreach

I've been trying to find (and replace) adjacent similar (of equal value) elements in a List of type int.

There is only 1 constraint that I'm keeping in mind while implementing the program:
- **That is, to find/replace elements which are adjacent to each other are of length =(or >) 3.**

Here's what I've done:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new[] {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};
        for (var i = 2; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] == list[i - 1] && list[i] == list[i - 2])
            {
                list[i] = 0;
                list[i - 1] = 0;
                list[i - 2] = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach(int item in list)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I am replacing all adjacent similar/equal values by 0. But there is one problem:
**The code runs fine if repeated value length is 3/6/9 and so on, and it does not change the value of digits to 0 if the length of repeated digits is anything but 3/6/9, etc**

If you run the program, you'll see the following **output**: 000330004 (since there are 3 number of 2s so it worked fine, but since there are 4 number of 4s so it ignored the last digit and did not convert it into 0).

WHAT I NEED: I understand what is happening, and why it's happening. I just can't seem to have it as I want it to work. I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: ... because you're never instructing your code to remove that 4th 4. Just have a very close look at your if clause. You're setting 3 values to 0 there. Not 4. Point being -- once those 3 are set to 0, the 4th 4 no longer qualifies to meet your if clause and thus gets ignored.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that's the best I could reach in-order to implement a class to find/replace the adjacent similar elements in a List. I know I'm only targeting the 3 values, but I don't know how else could I target all the adjacent values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for an arbitrary number of integers:

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<int> data = new List<int> ();
            data.AddRange (new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 });

            int instance_counter = 0;
            int previous_end = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count - 1; i++) {
                instance_counter++;
                if (data [i] != data [i + 1]) {
                    if (instance_counter > 2) {
                        for (int j = previous_end; j < i + 1; j++) {
                            data [j] = 0;
                        }
                        previous_end = i + 1;
                    }
                    instance_counter = 0;
                    previous_end = i + 1;
                }
            }
            if (instance_counter > 2) {
                for (int j = previous_end; j < data.Count; j++) {
                    data [j] = 0;
                }
            }
            foreach (int x in data) {
                Console.WriteLine (x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For posting such an interesting question. Well, I thought it was interesting anyhow. Gave me something to do while I should actually be sleeping (it's 4 AM). ;)

Comment: Quick question: Do you know why by the end of the list, it's not taking "instance_counter" into consideration and is making/replacing entities with 0, even if they are of length 2, and not length 3 (or greater than 3). For e.g. use the following data set: {4, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6}. Thanks a lot though, works great except this minor bug.

Comment: Yes, I do know and so could you have. ;) Anyhow, already corrected, see the code. All it needed was a change in the final if clause for instance counter. 2 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

The last one doesn't get converted, because the 3 **4's** before it get converted to 0 first.

7th iteration:
`{00033**444**4}`
8th iteration:
`{00033**000**4}`
9th iteration:
`{000330004} //the 9th iteration loops over the 8th one.`

What you should do is find the start and end of any repeated numbers, and then modify their values.  Your current method replaces 3 similar values, 3 at a time.

Comment: While you didn't offer a solution in code, you did diagnose the problem and give a verbal solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace repeated elements when you find 3 of them - count them. Keep the last value and the number of elements (preceding the current) that are equal to this value. When the value changes to something else - replace counted number of elements if that number is `>=3`.

```
int previous = list[0];
int count = 1;
int i;
for (i = 1; i < list.Length; i++)
{
  if (list[i] == previous)
  {
    count++;
  } 
  else 
  {
    if (count >= 3)
    {
      for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
        list[i-j] = 0;
    } 
    count = 1;
    previous = list[i];
  }
}
// repeat the else logic from the loop above:
if (count >= 3)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++)
    list[i-j] = 0;
}
```

Conceptually, it is the same idea that you accepted as the answer to your question [Count similar adjacent items in List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648409/count-similar-adjacent-items-in-liststring)

Comment: You see, it's not just repeated numbers. It's repeated numbers which are adjacent. If it were just repeated numbers, a simple if-else loop would've done the trick for me to count and replace the elements.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution using LINQ.

```
List<int> data = new List<int>();
data.AddRange(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 });
var consecutiveIndexes = data.Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
                             .OrderBy(container => container.Index)
                             .GroupBy(container => container.Value, group => group.Index)
                             // Get consecutive indexes where count > 2 and elements are consecutive
                             .Where(group => group.Count() > 2 &&
                                             //return next index if previous index is one less than the next index else -1
                                             group.Aggregate((prevIndex, nextIndex) => prevIndex + 1 == nextIndex ? nextIndex : -1) > -1) 
                             .SelectMany(index => index);
var filteredData = data.Select((x, i) => consecutiveIndexes.Contains(i) ? 0 : x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise you already have an answer, but I couldn't sleep, and seeing your question gave my mind something to do. I originally wanted to use [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/bb548651) but couldn't do it in a *nice* way, but still wanted to try solving your problem in a different way.

I've tested it with some random lists (including an empty list, and, of course, your list), and it works for all cases I can think of.

edit: I looked at your code again and came up with a much simpler, but boring answer (only minor modifications to what you did) so have posted that (method 2) for completeness.

---

**Method 1: the 'fun' way**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new[] {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};

        // tuples is a list of Tuple<current value, number of repetitions of value>
        var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        var currentTuple = Tuple.Create(0, 0);
        foreach ( var value in list )
        {
            bool newValue = value != currentTuple.Item1;
            if ( newValue && currentTuple.Item2 != 0 )
               tuples.Add(currentTuple);

            currentTuple = Tuple.Create(
                value,
                newValue ? 1 : currentTuple.Item2 + 1);
        }
        tuples.Add(currentTuple);

        var result = new List<int>();
        foreach ( var tuple in tuples )
            result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(tuple.Item2 > 2 ? 0 : tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2));

        foreach ( var item in result )
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

---

**Method 2: the boring way**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new[] {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4};
        var copy = list.ToArray();
        for (var i = 2; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] == list[i - 1] && list[i] == list[i - 2])
            {
                copy[i] = 0;
                copy[i - 1] = 0;
                copy[i - 2] = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach ( int item in copy )
            Console.Write(item);
    }
}
```